# How to just get remote changes for a specific file?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

There is a conflict on a file but it's ok, I just like to take the edits done remotely.
So, I choosed "overwrite" and at the question "do you want to overwrite local changes?" I said "yes" and I can see that my local file was overwritten.

Problem is that egit keeps telling me about the conflict, but there is no conflict anymore!!!
And now I am stuck because if I try to commit my last changes (which are for different files) I get a "non fast forward" error...is git idiot or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to rebase the code to the remote one. Then apply your changes to that. Then you can push the changes to the remote server.